# Custom Identity Provider for OpenAM/OpenSSO

Tags: java, single-sign-on, opensso, openam

We are looking to use OpenAM/OpenSSO to act as a SSO provider. We need, however, to have OpenAM use our mongo datastore under the hood to manage its authentication needs.

With this in mind, I found this: http://www.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/notes/installing_a_custom_opensso_identity_repository/ which looks promising.

Apparently, this should allow me to add an "Access Manager Repository plugin", but I have since read this:

> The Access Manager Repository plugin
>   is also called amSDK or legacy SDK as
>   it  provides downward compatibility to
>   work with the existing Sun Access
>   Manager 7.x  version deployment
>   identity stores. This repository is
>   tightly coupled with the Oracle  DSEE
>   server;  hence, will not work with any
>   other LDAP servers.

This makes me wonder whether this is really what I want to create, being as though I dont want to be tied to Oracle DSEE server (whatever this is).

Basically, where should I be looking to implement a custom Identity provider for openAM?

Comment: Are you looking for way to authenticate users in OpenAM against your own mongo db?

Comment: Is mongo db have JDBC driver?

Comment: @wjans - yes we are. @David - There seems to be an experimental JDBC driver, but as mongodb is not relational DB Im not sure it makes sense.

Comment: You can create JDBC datastore in openam and define what table/view and what fields you authenticate on. This way you dont have to write Custom Authentication Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Custom Authentication Module](http://wikis.sun.com/display/OpenSSO/Custom+Authentication+Module) in OpenAM.

This is an easy way to authenticate users against a custom datastore.  You need to configure callbacks (Eg. username/password) which you need to process in a custom written `com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AMLoginModule`. The runtime values for these callbacks will be provided as input to process the login module.  Based on those values, you should decide whether the user can be authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1):

For a custom identity repository, specifically, this is likely what you'll want to do:

Develop and Deploy a Custom IdRepo Plugin 
https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Develop+and+Deploy+a+Custom+IdRepo+Plugin

I'm also doing this for MongoDB - hopefully it will go well.  If the logic of your login process is sufficiently unique, then a Custom 'Auth' module is necessary.  I like keeping the data access layer separate from the auth process, however  -rather than having connect statements in the Auth module.

Answer (score 1):

See section 16.3 and beyond in the OpenAM Developer's Guide, http://openam.forgerock.org/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-identity-repo-spi.html