# OpenAM: MongoDB or SQL-DB as external identity store/repository

Tags: openam, identity-management, forgerock

**Question**: Is it possible to set up MongoDB or a SQL-DB as an external identity store/repository for OpenAM >13.5, and if so, can you point out a good resource, or even better, a "How to ..." guide?

**Problem**: In the [OpenAM 13.5 Installation Guide](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/install-guide/index.html) there is a section on ["Preparing an External Identity Repository"](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/install-guide/#prepare-identity-repository). However, the section points you to the section ["Data Store Requirements"](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/release-notes/index.html#data-store-requirements) which in turn list the supported data stores as:

- Embedded OpenDJ
- External OpenDJ
- Oracle Unified Directory
- Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition
- Microsoft Active Directory
- IBM Tivoli Directory Server

So if I understand correctly, using a database like MongoDB is not supported anymore.

**Top Search Results:** The best resource that I could find so far is this Youtube tutorial [MySQL Database As Identity Repository for ForgeRock OpenAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jeds4ir7Ew&ab_channel=RajeshRajasekharan) by Rajesh Rajasekharan. But considering the list of supported data stores above and the fact that the video is from 2015, I would expect that it is not valid anymore for the current OpenAM versions.

The [best StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6457711/11918697) that I could find is eight years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Open Identity Platform Community [OpenAM](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM) version, there is no MongoDB support yet. But you can try **Database Repository (Early Access)** datastore type with [MongoDB JDBC driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/).

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Maxim! Since I've had quite a few problems configuring OpenAM, could you be more specific on how to set this up or point me to a resource? I know I need to select `Database Repository (Early Access)` under `Realms > Realm Name > Data Stores` and I have an idea where to place the DB connection file. However, I'm still largely in the dark about how to configure the DB and OpenAM.

Comment: Just a note: If Open Identity Platform Community OpenAM has not fixed the various bugs of the original OpenAM code, then you need to be careful. The RDBMS IdRepo implementation was EA for years but never got any attention.

Comment: Hmm, that really is a bummer. If I understand [this](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-11184) issue correctly they actually wanted to remove the "Database Repository (Early Access)" option. It is tagged as resolved. However, the option is still available in version 14.5.4.

Comment: @Maixm, What version of Open Identity Platform are you referring to here?

Comment: @Maxim Thomas, What Openam version are you referring to?